# Can't Verify Mailgun Receiving and Tracking Records

Tags: dns, mailgun

I'm trying to set up DNS receiving and tracking records for Mailgun. The DNS sending records were verified and work fine, but for some reason the receiving records and tracking records don't get verified.

The domain I'm using is mg.optimizeprice.com and the DNS provider I'm using is Dynadot. There are two mx records that it wants me to set up. I took screenshots of the Mailgun DNS records page as well as the Dynadot DNS records page as I have them set up right now. What do I need to change to get this to work?

[image]

[image]

Also, here is the output of `dig optimizeprice.com mx`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.8-Ubuntu <<>> optimizeprice.com mx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8708
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;optimizeprice.com.             IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
optimizeprice.com.      10800   IN      CNAME   curved-aardvark-xbc5jxmn5ja3pdaq403yoxab.herokudns.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
herokudns.com.          10      IN      SOA     dns1.p05.nsone.net. hostmaster.nsone.net. 1563353642 600 900 1209600 10

;; Query time: 41 msec
;; SERVER: 75.75.75.75#53(75.75.75.75)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 17 01:55:08 PDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 176
```

Comment: It turned out that adding a CNAME record to the mg subdomain pointing to the same URL as the primary domain name ended up getting the receiving record values to populate on Mailgun. But I still can't get the tracking record's value to populate on Mailgun.